# Disconnect from GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, location, google-api-client

In my app i connect to Google Api Client. Once connected i request a location and set a timeout in the location request. If i get the location in callback i disconnect from the client. But in case of a timeout while fetching location i get no callback. How can i disconnect from the client in this case?

here is the code for onLocationChanged()

```
 @Override public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
       //app specific logic here
    }
```